# Global eventListener, when focus inside the texiInput

Tags: apache-flex, focus, listener, global, textinput

I'm trying to make a global eventListener. Everything works fine, the `KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN` fires all the time .. except the cases when the textInput has a focus.

Here's how I attach listener:

```
FlexGlobals.topLevelApplication.systemManager.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, keyDownHandler, true);
```

I've tried both (use capture and without it). What am I missing?

Thanks for your time :)

Comment: I guess the TextInput stops the propagation of the KeyboardEvent event.
Maybe you can extend it and re-dispatch the event yourself

Comment: Might work in a small application, but what to do in a huge one? .. I'll make a suicide if I'll count, how many textInputs I should replace xD .. But anyway, thanks for a tip :)

Comment: I've never figured out how to use capture... This should be the perfect occasion, if you have further info...

Comment: You can still monkey patch the original TextInput, risky solution but I don't have anything better sorry

Comment: @Kodiak In my case, it doesn't matter, when to catch this event. I've said that cause not all the components have all these capturing phases .. and I've tried both variants. If interested in event-flow, read this: http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=16_Event_handling_4.html By default, the flex adds listener to the moment, when event is bubbling up, but you able to catch it earlier, just say `useCapture=true` and the event will be caught at the capturing phase.

Comment: @Florian F Well, it's not my way to solve the problems, let's see .. maybe anybody has the solution ;)

Comment: Well I know the theory but I've never managed to see it actually doing its job :)

Comment: @Kodiak :) hehe .. well, not this time, but maybe my next question would give you a better example.

Answer (score 1):

First, I don't know why you're using the `systemManager` as your listener object since it's not part of the display list, hence it can't get bubbling events.  Second, using FlexGlobals isn't the best way of doing things (personally, other than using it for popups, I don't see many reasons why you should use it).

If you want to listen for a global event, just put it on the stage.  Every view component has a 'stage' property which points to the main stage of your flex app.  Try this:

```
stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, onKeyDown);
```

Comment: Ok .. here we go: 1) Seems like use of `systemManager`, rather than `stage` was my mistake; 2) I'm using FlexGlobals, cause I'm attaching the listeners in AS class, which has no explicitly base class specified. That stops me from referring `stage`, like you've suggested.

Comment: Ah, then I guess if you're using an AS class, that could be acceptable.  What I personally would prefer from a coding standpoint is that the class you're instantiating would take in a `DisplayObject` as a constructor argument unless it's not being instantiated anywhere on the display list.  Then in that case use FlexGlobals.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm... I don't really understand what's the problem.

Here's a simple app:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
               xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
               xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" minWidth="955" minHeight="600"
               keyDown="application1_keyDownHandler(event)"
               creationComplete="application1_creationCompleteHandler(event)"
               >

    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            import flash.utils.getQualifiedClassName;

            import mx.core.FlexGlobals;
            import mx.events.FlexEvent;
            protected function application1_keyDownHandler(event:KeyboardEvent):void
            {
                trace("Key Down Handler: key = " + event.keyCode);
            }

            protected function application1_creationCompleteHandler(event:FlexEvent):void
            {
                FlexGlobals.topLevelApplication.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, tlaKeyDownHandler);
                FlexGlobals.topLevelApplication.systemManager.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, smKeyDownHandler);
            }

            protected function tlaKeyDownHandler(event:KeyboardEvent):void
            {
                trace("Top Level Application Key Down Handler: key = " + event.keyCode);
            }

            protected function smKeyDownHandler(event:KeyboardEvent):void
            {
                trace("System Manager Key Down Handler: key = " + event.keyCode);
            }




        ]]>
    </fx:Script>

    <fx:Declarations>
        <!-- Place non-visual elements (e.g., services, value objects) here -->
    </fx:Declarations>
    <s:Button x="130" y="135" label="Button"/>
    <s:ComboBox x="130" y="54"/>
    <s:TextInput x="130" y="99"/>
</s:Application>
```

Here's an output:

Key Down Handler: key = 65

Top Level Application Key Down Handler: key = 65

System Manager Key Down Handler: key = 65

Key Down Handler: key = 83

Top Level Application Key Down Handler: key = 83

System Manager Key Down Handler: key = 83

Key Down Handler: key = 68

Top Level Application Key Down Handler: key = 68

System Manager Key Down Handler: key = 68

As you can see, I created three different components in the application and used three different methods to catch the event. And in all cases(when one of the components have focus) event is fired and catched.

Probably you didn't tell us something important.

Comment: Indeed, ok, let's clarify my situation a bit. The first and probably, the most important difference from my code is that my mx is referring to "http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml". Next - I'm attaching listeners in a custom class (with no base class specified explicitly).